# how to bind multi html5 canvases with a div

Tags: jquery, html

i have a div which have multiple canvas on it and each canvas has a particular image  e.g a div having 4 canvases on it.
Now how can i get all the canvases on their specific positions along with the div behind them?

Comment: Please add your own research around this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you post your HTML please ? It'll be easier to help you.

If I have understood you have to select all canvas of div element :

```
$('div canvas')
```

After thanks to forEach you can set css position :

```
$('div canvas').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'top': '10px', 'left' : '15px'}
})
```

I hope i answered your question

Comment: div with three canvases

<div id="d1"  >
    <canvas id='cv0' width = 150 height = 150>
           
    </canvas>
    <canvas id='cv1' width = 150 height = 150>
           
    </canvas>
    <canvas id='cv2' width = 150 height = 150>
          
    </canvas>

</div>

Comment: So you can set any attribute thanks in each

if($(this).attr('id') == 'cv0'){
    $(this).css(rule, value);
}

For example